# Display in the Details View --> Task Form: Sorting Predecessors by Task ID, not alphabetically

Tags: ms-project

I'm using MS Project 2013 Professional

In the Details View using Task Form, displaying Predecessor view, it is sorting alphabetically by Task Name when I would rather see it sorted by Task ID.  I do not even see the task ID, only the task name.

Q:  How can I change it to display and sort by Task ID, then show the task name?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sorry, there's no way to modify the predecessors presentation in the standard MSP user interface (e.g. task form, task details form, task information dialog.)  Predecessors are typically sorted in the order that they have been added to the task, not alphabetically.
2. If you can't see the ID in these forms, then the forms may be corrupted.  You might need to repair the installation or restore the global.mpt file.
3. Some add-ins provide forms with more control; they are not free.